# Bootstrap modal dialog set attributes from javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How to set theese attributes: data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" to modal that is opened from javascript with:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS you can do this:

```
$('#myModal').modal({show: true, backdrop : false, keyboard : false});
```

In HTML you can do this:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
```

Use the *second* one only if you want it in HTML and always want these attributes.